# How to fix Y axis in jqplot

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I am using jqplot for charting report in my current application..

I have one `ChartCtrl` div which is using as a chart placeholder. 
And one Parent Div is controlled for positioning chart in page. I am calculating the width of the chart dynamically based on the no. of bars are present and initiate the scroll for the same for parent div, so that if more bars are plotted i can scroll the chart horizontally.

But when I scroll the chart, the Left `Yaxis` is also scrolling which is expected.. But is there any way to `fix the left Y-axis` only the chart content is scrollable in jqplot.

Please provide some suggestions on this.

Comment: I have implemented the same scenario in my application. what i have done is that i have drawn the axis separately and aligned it to the left of the graph. that ways you can scroll the graph and the axis would stay fixed on left side.

Comment: thanks for the response. can you please briefly explain the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same issue, but I solved by using little bit change in jqplot.css.  Just in your html add this style class:

```
<style type="text/css">
        .jqplot-axis.jqplot-yaxis{
            position : fixed !important;
            }
            .jqplot-series-canvas {
                overflow-x : scroll;
            }
</style>
```

If your problem is solved then just vote...